# Close a window in Avalonia GUI

Tags: c#, .net-core, mvvm, avaloniaui

I have created a login screen using Avalonia UI according to the MVVM pattern. What I am struggling to do is when a user clicks the login button I want to close that login page and redirect to a new window. So below you can find the code.

**MainWindow.axaml**

```
<Label>Username</Label>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Watermark="Username"></TextBox>
<Label>Password</Label>
<TextBox PasswordChar="*" Text="{Binding Password}" Watermark="Password"></TextBox>
<Button Command="{Binding Login}"  Width="315">Login</Button>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public void Login()
            {
                Users userDetails = Database.createDB();
    
                if (Name == userDetails.userName & Password == userDetails.password) {
                    var window1 = new Window1();
                    window1.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Text = "Invalid username and password.";
                }
            }
```

So I can create a new window but I can’t close the login screen. So how can I close the Login Screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `Close()` when you want to close the current window.
Note that if your `ApplicationLifetime` in your App.xaml.cs is set to -
`ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose` you will need to update it's `MainWindow` property to the newly created window.

Comment: What about if you want to close the `App : Application` class? (because it's a trayicon app)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You can use `if (Application.Current?.ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime lifetime) lifetime.Shutdown();`
For other types of `ApplicationLifetime` I'm not sure if there is any intended way.

Comment: It sounds like this should be simplified here by a simple function call on the application class. (buildin in avaloniaui )